# Select column within current row (Google Sheets Script)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've been trying to make a script that is capable of changing a value in a cell dependent on a value from another cell in the same row.

Here's the code I got so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {

      var ss = e.source,
          sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
          range = e.range,
          columnNumberToWatch = 1; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc;

  if (sheet.getName() === "Ark1" && e.value === "Commisioner" && e.range.columnStart === columnNumberToWatch) {

    e.range.columnStart = 5;
    e.range.setValue("Test");

  }

}
```

Script changes the edited cell when e.range.columnStart is not set to a value, but when it is nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = e.source,
      sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      range = e.range,
      columnNumberToWatch = 1; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc;
  if (sheet.getName() === "Ark1" && e.value === "Commisioner" && 
     e.range.columnStart === columnNumberToWatch) {
     sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 5).setValue("Test");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :)